# Realmのインスタンスを作成する際のpath指定ができない

Tags: swift, realm

```
let realm = try! Realm(path: 読み込みたいpath名)
```

のように以前はできたのですが、Realmのバージョンが1.0になってから

```
Argument labels '(path:)' do not match any available overloads
```

という警告文が出るようになってしまいました。

この警告文を解消するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか。
pathに代わる引数があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`path`引数は少し前にSwiftの標準ライブラリに合わせる形で、`fileURL`というパラメータに変更されました。

https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.99.0/

今後は`Realm(fileURL:)`を使うか、

```
try! Realm(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file"))
```

`Realm.Configuration`を用いてファイルパスを設定します。

```
try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file")))
```

Comment: fileURLを用いてやってみたところ、うまくいきました！

ありがとうございました！